# How can I organize the bibliography in order of appearance?

Tags: bibliographies, organisation

I heard there's a command to organize the bibliography in the order of citation in the text. I looked up in Kopka, but found nothing. How can I do that?

PS. I'm using \begin{thebibliography} + \bibitem

Comment: It looks like you're building the bibliography entirely by hand. Is this impression correct? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico I guess that's right. I put one by one. Each in a /bibitem.

Comment: If you build the bibliography by hand, *you* are in charge of *everything* -- including the order in which each and every `\bibitem` appears inside the `thebibliography` environment.

Comment: If you would switch to `biblatex` or `bibtex`, there would be automatic ways.